# hibernate map relation with 2 tables, one with enum values

Tags: hibernate, enums, hibernate-mapping, join

I have 4 tables, customer (klant) a join table, customer_has_address, address and adres type. The join table has the id's of the other three tables. [table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJzYf.png).

I have my pojo's set up and have linked klant to adres correctly. Now I want to add in the adres_type. This is for example "billing address", there's a fixed list.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "klant")
public class KlantPojo {

// ------------ VARIABLES ---------------------------------

    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Id
    private int idKlant = 0;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "klant_heeft_adres", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "klantId", nullable = false, updatable = false) },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "adresId", nullable = false, updatable = false) } )

    private Set<AdresPojo> adressen = new HashSet<>(0);
}
```

So how and where do I add in adres type? Should I put a one-on-one relation in the address pojo? Can I add this in the same join as address and klant. And because this is an enum I don't want anything to overwrite the adres_type table but to get the required values from it.

I'm not sure what I'm trying to do is called making it hard to search, so any pointers in the right direction are greatly appreciated.

Comment: A join table is limited to two tables. You need to map the klant_heeft_adres table as en entity. I would also recomment to give it an additional ID column service as autogenerated PK, just like your other entities.

Comment: Thanks JB, not what I wanted to hear, but good to know I can stop looking this type of solution and start looking for something else.